# JavaScript Map with objects for keys: duplicate entries

Tags: javascript

According to the [mdn webdocs on JavaScript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) `Map`:

> A `Map`'s keys can be any value (including functions, objects, or any primitive).

However:

```
const map = new Map();
console.log(map.size); // 0

map.set({someProperty: 0}, 0);
console.log(map.size); // 1

map.set({someProperty: 0}, 0);
console.log(map.size); // 2 <-- what? shouldn't this be 1 still?
```

The documentation indicates that it's fine to use an object as a key. So how can I insert an object with the same key into the `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object is unique (even if its keys and values are identical to those of another one), so when you use different objects as keys, each will occupy a different entry in the `Map`.

See more at [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) on MDN.

```js
const map = new Map();
console.log(map.size); // 0

const a = {someProperty: 0};
const b = {someProperty: 0};

console.log(a === b); // false

map.set(a, 0);
console.log(map.size); // 1

map.set(b, 0);
console.log(map.size); // 2

const c = a;

console.log(a === c); // true

map.set(c, 1);
console.log(map.size); // 2

console.log(map.get(a)); // 1 (not 0)
```

Comment: Aargh! Thanks. Why didn't that occur to me? Idiot.

Answer (score 1):

The two objects have different references.

If you use the same object both times, you only have one entry:

```js
const map = new Map();
const key = { someProperty: 0 };
map.set(key, 0);
map.set(key, 0);
console.log(map.size);
```

Comment: Aargh! Thanks. Why didn't that occur to me? Idiot.